# Any Upgrade Header for telling client application(Android/IOS) to upgrade app?

Tags: android, ios, rest, http, asp.net-web-api

Is there any stranded way to tell the client app using http-api(rpc/rest) to upgrade the app in order to continue. My client app will send server an header(say X-AppVersion) to tell the server about the current application version. The server need to return an Upgrade header(if required) to tell client to upgrade in order to continuously us the app. My clients are Android and IOS.

HTTP 426 UpgradeRequired is fine here?

Comment: The "standard way" is to support both old and new clients from your Web service.

Comment: @CommonsWare, we are doing. But sometimes we require that the app should upgrade